# how to remove time from Highstock chart at navaigater bar?

Tags: javascript, charts, javascript-framework, highcharts

i use Highstock for creating chart  i try to remove time form the navigation bar or decrease floating point of that point but not able to remove

how to remove it. attach image with this for more information [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your `xAxis` definition

```
...
xAxis: {
  ...
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
  }
}
...
```

This should limit the output. Time has a resolution of 1/1000 of a second and thats why you have 3 decimals showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You can change datimelabelformats (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) as dgw posted above or use xaxis label formatter() http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter and http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#highcharts.dateFormat()